# BASH - How to make a variable have her value equal to a hidden file name

Tags: bash, hidden-files

im trying to make a script for a school project but i can't solve this problem.
I will leave my code with comments, i hope you can understand my problem.
Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash

directory=$HOME/.impressora
imp=0

mkdir -p $directory
#check if $HOME/.impressora exists, if not, create it

if [ ! -f "$directory/.*" ]
# if there is no ".something" file in "$HOME/.impressora"
then echo "" > $directory/.200
# then create a file called ".200" in "$HOME/.impressora"
fi

creditos=$(echo  "$directory/*" | cut -f 3 -d '.')
# here is my problem, i want the value of the variable "creditos" to be what comes after the "." on the file in "$HOME/.impressora" , so, in # this case, the file in "$HOME/.impressora" is called ".200" , so the objective is to make "creditos" = 200
# I hope you can help me figure out whats wrong!

if [ $1 = "lp" ] 
# if the first variable is "lp" then.
then
    if [ -d $directory ] && [ $creditos > 0 ]
    #if "$/HOME/.impressora" exists and $creditos > 0
    then 
        echo "" > $directory/lp-$imp
        # create an empty file called "lp-$imp" (in wich $imp will be a number)
        ((imp++))
        $cred=$creditos
        ((cred--))
        mv $directory/.$creditos $directory/.$cred
        # the objective here is to change the name of the file in "$HOME/.impressora" , so in this case it would go from ".200" to ".199"
    # and so on and so on. 
    else 
        echo "Diretorio inexistente ou creditos insuficientes"
    fi
```

### **UPDATE:**

I just found myself a solution for my problem!

> As the file as no name (because it starts with a dot) it's
>   automatically the first file to appear at your directory is that one.
>   So first you need to "**ls -a**" your dir. Next you need to jump the
>   two "files" that appear which are the:
>
> > .
>
> and
>
> > ..
>
> So, you do the "**head -3**" command so you can select the 3 first
>   lines (files) of the folder.  Next you need to select the last one of
>   those 3 so you pipe it again and do the "**tail -1**"
>
> Finally you need to remove the dot in the .200 file so you can save
>   only the value to the var, to do this you have to pipe "**cut -f2
>   -d"."**"
>
> Basicly you need to replace the
>
> ```
> creditos=$(echo $directory/.* | cut -c7-)
> ```
>
> with
>
> ```
> creditos=$(ls -a $directory | head -3 | tail -1 | cut -f2 -d".")
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`$directory/*` expands to only non-hidden files by default.

If you do `shopt -s dotglob`, `$directory/*` will match all files (including `.` and `..`). You will want to undo it with `shopt -u dotglob` after.

`$directory/.*`, you will only match the hidden files (regardless of `dotglob`). If you assume there is nothing else in that directory, `echo .* | cut -c7-` should give you `200`.